# How to dynamically add a selected attribute to an option element in ASP MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core, drop-down-menu

I would like to add a selected attribute tag to a select option based on a value in the model that is passed to the view. The following code results in an error that states:

> must not have c# in the elements attribute declaration area

I am not sure how to do this elegantly or properly.

```
<select class="custom-select-sm" name="[@(i)].User" id="userSelect">
    @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
    {
        string selText;
        if (Model.Listings[i].User.ID == user.ID)
            selText = "selected";
        else
            selText = string.Empty;

        <option value="@user.ID" @selText>@user.Name</option>;
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

easy way:

```
<option value="@user.ID" @((Model.Listings[i].User.ID == user.ID)?"selected":"")>@user.Name</option>
```

or use Razor `@functions` :

```
<option value="@user.ID" @(SetSelectedClass(Model.Listings[i].User.ID,user.ID))>@user.Name</option>


@functions{
    public string SetSelectedClass(string modelUserId,string userId)
    {
       return (modelUserId==userId)?"selected":"";
    }
}
```

about Razor @functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#functions